# "Invalid geometry value" with LeafletGeoAdmin

Tags: python, geodjango

I can not add information via the admin, "Invalid geometry value" always appear.

[image: Invalid geometry value]

django==1.9.12

django-googlemap==0.5

django-leaflet==0.21.0

psycopg2==2.6.2

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from ascblog.models import Newspaper
from leaflet.admin import LeafletGeoAdmin
# Register your models here.
class ascblogAdmin(LeafletGeoAdmin):
    list_display=('date','archtype','structure','changnew','forman','content','location_name','location')
    list_filter = ('date','archtype','structure','changnew','forman','content','location_name','location')

admin.site.register(Newspaper,ascblogAdmin)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class Newspaper(models.Model):
    location = models.TextField(blank=True,max_length=5000)
    location = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural ="Newspaper"
```

settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*iqh-9kl3uo8813)4+u8+@&l_w&u43#_t*u2j2qya8hdmpqtgc'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH ='C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/geos_c.dll'
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    'leaflet',
    'ascblog',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'archproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'archproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME':'alldb',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '0',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '4321',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


LEAFLET_CONFIG={
    'DEFAULT_CENTER':(24,121),
    'DEFAULT_ZOOM':7,
    'MAX_ZOOM':16,
    'MIN_ZOOM':5,
    'SCALE':'both',
    'ATTRIBUTION_PREFIX':'HELLO I AM A STUDENT'

}
```

i have postgis and postgis_topology: [pgadmin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGPhi.jpg)

Comment: add `python` tag to get your question noticed...

Comment: You have too `location` fields in your code above.

Comment: Works for me with `django==1.10.6` and `django-leaflet==0.21.0`

Comment: "@Udi"
i use 1.10.6 can't runserver
error message:
**django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis' is not an available database backend. Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql',and 'sqlite'.
Error was: Cannot import name ‘GDALRaster’.**

Comment: i use 1.9.12 will normal
but have to add code
**GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH ='C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/geos_c.dll'**